# GLFW Error (65540): Invalid image dimensions for window icon

Tags: c++, glfw

I tried to add icon to my application window like this:

```
int width, height, channels;
unsigned char* pixels = stbi_load("resources/slika1.png", &width, &height, &channels, 4);

m_Icon[0].width = width;
m_Icon[0].height = height;
m_Icon[0].pixels = pixels;

glfwSetWindowIcon(m_Window, 1, m_Icon);

stbi_image_free(m_Icon[0].pixels);
```

And I get error from title.

I tried to google correct image size but had no luck. Also tried different sizes of png... still same error...

Comment: Check for any errors as stated in the docs: https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#gadd7ccd39fe7a7d1f0904666ae5932dc5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stbi_load` failed to load your image. `pixels` is null, and `width`, `height` and `channels` are uninitialized. Their contents are [undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior).

The error is reported in [`windows.c`, line 552](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/3fa2360720eeba1964df3c0ecf4b5df8648a8e52/src/window.c#L552), because the provided image dimensions contain a negative number, or zero.

```c
m_Icon[0].width = width;
m_Icon[0].height = height;
```

You are initializing the image with data that was not initialized by STB; the data is read from the stack's memory, and this data is undefined in this context.

You need to do proper error handling:

```c
bool loadIcon(void) {
    int width, height, channels;
    unsigned char* pixels = stbi_load("resources/slika1.png", &width, &height, &channels, 4);

    if (!pixels) {
        return false;
    }

    GLFWimage image;
    image.width = width;
    image.height = height;
    image.pixels = pixels;

    glfwSetWindowIcon(m_Window, 1, &image);

    stbi_image_free(pixels);
    return true;
}
```

Side note: you're assigning `pixels` to an outer variable, `m_Icon`, but then immediately deallocating this data with `stbi_image_free(m_Icon[0].pixels)`. You can not use this data after freeing it.